# What's the highest score you can get on Canabalt?

Tags: canabalt

The all time scores for Canabalt stop just before 300,000. That makes me wonder whether the game ends at that point or if it's just that nobody has reached that score yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Canabalt is an endless run game, It only gets more difficult as the game goes on. Reason why the scores are similar on top rank is because the game probably gets technically impossible to beat (too many jumps close together or unjumpable heights).

Comment: The highest score is exactly 299,999. Part of me thinks it could also be a bug rather than difficulty that's stopping players.

Comment: Is there a lot of scores at 299,999? If so then you could be right.

Comment: There are a couple scores near it, all by the same person.